Timestamp handling: postgres vs pinot
I got this from chatgpt on time stamp suppport in postgres and apache pinot:

PostgreSQL natively supports the TIMESTAMP data type, allowing it to
handle temporal data effectively. On the other hand, Apache Pinot does
not have a native TIMESTAMP type. Instead, it relies on various
formats and representations, like EPOCH and SIMPLE_DATE_FORMAT, to
handle time-related data. Thus, when using Pinot, you often need to
define your timestamp handling explicitly in the schema.

In pinot codebase I can see different classes handling time stamp. And I assume postgres must also have something similar.
So what does it mean in terms of difference between internal handling of date time by postgres and pinot?
